# Package 'ros-indigo-urdfdom-headers' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm having trouble installting ros indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. I've followed all of the instructions on [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu), but when I run sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full I get the following errors:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've narrowed the problem down, it won't install because it can't find the package ros-indigo-urdfdom-headers:

```
user@computer:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-urdfdom-headers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ros-indigo-urdfdom-headers is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ros-indigo-urdfdom-headers' has no installation candidate
```

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks

Jamie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185659/package-%27ros-indigo-urdfdom-headers%27-has-no-installation-candidate/) by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [syrnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/18511/syrnick/) on 2014-07-09**:
I'm seeing the same issue when re-provisioning my VM (https://github.com/ros-chef/ros-web-dev-vm, see the quickstart section to reproduce).

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-09**:
What are your apt sources?

**Comment by [syrnick](https://answers.ros.org/users/18511/syrnick/) on 2014-07-09**:\

```
vagrant@ros-web-dev:~$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-indigo.list 
deb     http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure of a solution, but this might be related to [rosdistro/issue/4633](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/4633).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-09**:
There appears to have been in issue with the ftp mirror syncing. I'm looking into it now. I'll track it on the above ticket.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-07-09**:
There isn't even a folder for http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-urdfdom -- it looks like urdfdom and headers are gone from public as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem and found out that it's due to manual installation of Gazebo before ros installation.
So i tried

```
sudo apt-get remove gazebo-* sdformat-*
```

and it helped.

---

Originally posted by [zakieh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20350/zakieh/) with karma: 11 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [petermitrano](https://answers.ros.org/users/21252/petermitrano/) on 2014-12-28**:
Seems you need to run this if you installed gazebo 4 before, then realized you need to remove it to install ROS. I ran this after running sudo apt-get remove gazebo4 and it allowed me install ros.
Thanks!